# Start/Stop/Restart individual vnc servers defined in /etc/sysconfig?

Tags: linux, redhat, remote-desktop, vnc

I have inherited responsibility for a RHEL 5 development box we are using at work that has been configured using a VNC server to allow multiple users to work on the machine at once.

The VNC service seems to have been configured along the lines of this post http://it.megocollector.com/?p=1300 so that it runs at boot and creates a set of predifened user desktops specified in /etc/sysconfig, great! However, occasionally it is necessary to add a new user, or start/stop/restart the service for an existing user. At the moment the only way we can do this is to start/stop/restart the VNCservice for all users, how can I do this for just the user in question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a session number for each user which is config in `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver`, for example:

```
VNCSERVERS="2:quanta"
```

You can use this number to start, stop a separate vnc session, something like this:

```
vncserver :2
vncserver -kill :2
```

---

**Edit**

You can custom the init script to make it can start a separate session, something as belows:

```
function start() {
    SESSION=$1
    ...
    vncserver :${SESSION} ${VNCSERVERARGS[${SESSION}]}
}
```

And in the `start)` of `case` statement, you can check the number of parameters to decide whether starting all or individual session:

```
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    start $2
else
    for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
    do
        start $display
    done
fi
```

Comment: True, this does work however it simply starts a vanilla vnc session on the numbered port as the user executing the command, it doesn't load the additional configuration (eg custom resolutions/users) that we have specified in /etc/sysconfig. We can start the server as a particular user using su to first change to that user in terminal, however none of the other options configured are used. Is there a way to start the numbered server using the configuration in /etc/sysconfig as well? Thanks!

Comment: You can append it to the end of command: `vncserver :2 -geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -nohttpd -localhost`.

Comment: Yes but surely this defeats the point of defining the options in the configuration file?

Comment: I've edited my above post to answer your question.