# vncserver for individual user doesn't work

Tags: vnc

Following the guide for [Start/Stop/Restart individual vnc servers defined in /etc/sysconfig?](https://serverfault.com/questions/298778/start-stop-restart-individual-vnc-servers-defined-in-etc-sysconfig), still I am not able to bring up a user's desktop. While `vncserver` says that this desktop is already running, the `-kill` option is unable to find that!!!

Please see the output below.

```
dar@cluster:~$ cat /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
VNCSERVERS="2:mahmood 3:darik 11:dar"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[11]="-geometry 1250x700"
dar@cluster:~$ vncserver :11
A VNC server is already running as :11
dar@cluster:~$ ps aux | grep Xvnc
dar     5815  0.0  0.0 105300   900 pts/5    S+   13:38   0:00 grep Xvnc
darik  6644  0.2  0.0 111864 39068 ?        S    Aug28 143:42 /usr/bin/Xvnc :3 -desktop cluster.scu.edu:3 (darik) -auth /home/darik/.Xauthority -geometry 1368x768 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/darik/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -pn
mahmood  20826  0.0  0.0 123348 49464 ?        S    Aug26  45:57 /usr/bin/Xvnc :2 -desktop cluster.scu.edu:2 (mahmood) -auth /home/mahmood/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/mahmood/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5902 -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -pn
dar@cluster:~$ vncserver -kill :11

Can't find file /home/dar/.vnc/cluster.scu.ac.ir:11.pid
You'll have to kill the Xvnc process manually

dar@cluster:~$
```

What is the problem and how can I fix that?

Comment: Try the :55 id... Next, try netstat -a | grep 5911 - do you see your vnc?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't configured the users to login using a desktop mangager, they likely need to configure their session using a `~/.xsession` file.

It may be simpler to configure VNC using XDMCP to start the session.  I've had success running [Remote Desktops with VNC and RDP](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/).  For VNC sessions, it worked better using XDMCP.  Using XRDP, the desktop gets launched by the XRDP daemon.